# Putting wampserver online

Tags: networking, router, dns, port-forwarding

I have two routers in my house. The first one, router 1 (R1) is from my internet supplier and it assigns the IP address 192.168.1.57 to the second router (R2). The second assigns the IP address 192.168.0.100 to my computer.

I have a local website that I want to be available online. Here is what I did already :

- Port forwarding on R1: every request on port 80 goes to R2
- Port forwarding on R2: every request on port 80 goes to my computer on port 80

R1 has a dynamic public ip adress, so I was trying to use no-ip, a website which provides a domain and takes care of the dynamic ip adress problem for me. I was asked to enter the router opened port so I could forward it to my computer. Port 80 is closed, but I know that I can't put another port because when users are going to type my website in their browser, I want them to not put any other information, like another port. So is there a way to open the external port 80 on my router?

Answer (score 1):

So when you type in your browser http://192.168.1.57 your wampserver works?
If this is true, it is R1 firewall which is stopping packets coming from the internet to your WAN IP address 80 port. Before I start is there a reason you have 2 routers? you can remove one of them and just have one Port forwarding rule.

1. For now, forget the no-ip dns service you have, and make your wampserver work with your Internet IP address. Go to your R1 router and look for the firewall or NAT section. (Sorry I cant be specific because every router is different) Check the port forwarding, and it has to look something like this:

**Router 1**

> From any host in wan Via any router IP at port 80 Forward to 192.168.1.57, port 80 in lan

which 192.168.1.57 is your **Router 2** Local IP

**Router 2**

> From any host in lan Via any router IP at port 80 Forward to 192.168.0.100, port 80 in lan

Look that the secret here is the **WAN** part in the **Router 1**

2. You shouldn't but sometimes you can have some problems when you have 2 networks not being part of the same subnet. You can also try changing the **Router 2** IP address to be 192.168.0.X

Try to use the formatting of the site (bold, italics, etc), so we can read much better your questions. Is my answer easy to read, isn't it?

Comment: I had made exactly what you told me before, take a look at the port forwarding in **R1** [*here*](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TA8GM.jpg) then on **R2** I did what you told me. take a look
[*R2*](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LDdU0.jpg) But actually look, first, when I was trying to check if the **external** port 80 was open on the public IP address **148.255.97.179**, it was **open**. After a little while, trying once again, it was **close**. Then I don't know why the port 80 varies open, then close. And is there any way so I can configure external port 80 to be always open ?

Comment: Some routers prevent NAT Loopback which mean access to a LAN IP using their public IP, due to could be considered a security flaw. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16343/is-nat-loopback-on-my-router-a-security-problem#16359 may be try to use your phone to access the public IP. I just visited your IP and it seems to be working just fine. Visité su IP y funciona de maravilla :D

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the answer if it was helpful by clicking in the green check symbols next to the up an downvote.

Comment: Hey @SylvestreNeffersonRolando could you mark this as your answer? gracias!